# how to merge excel file with python django

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe

i use google translation
I am making a website using Django.
I am trying to upload 4 excel files so that one excel file can be downloaded.
After defining the views.py function for each file, modifying the Excel file and then defining a function that merges the files into one, implements the download function.
Excel editing for each file is possible, but the merge function is not implemented, so I ask a question.
Current code is below(ignore the korean)

views.py

```
import pandas as pd 
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect
from io import BytesIO 

def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")

def health_upload(request): 
    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.FILES.get("health_input")
        건강2 = pd.read_excel(file)
        건강2.rename(columns= {"성명" : "근로자명"} , inplace=True) 
        건강2.rename(columns= {"주민등록번호" : "생년월일"} , inplace=True)
        건강2["생년월일"] = 건강2["생년월일"].str[: -8]
        건강2 = 건강2.set_index(["근로자명", "생년월일"])
        건강기본 = 건강2.iloc[: , -1 : ].copy()
        건강기본["개인부담금"] = 건강기본.가입자총납부할보험료 
        건강기본["사업주부담금"] = 건강기본.가입자총납부할보험료 
        건강기본.drop(columns = ["가입자총납부할보험료"], inplace=True) 
        return render(request, "index.html")

def national_upload(request): 
    if request.method == "POST":
        file2 = request.FILES.get("national_input")
        aaa = pd.read_excel(file2) 
        aaa.rename(mapper = {"가입자명" : "근로자명"}, axis="columns", inplace=True)
        aaa.rename(mapper = {"주민번호" : "생년월일"}, axis="columns", inplace=True)
        aaa["생년월일"] = aaa["생년월일"].str[: -8]
        국민기본 = aaa.set_index(["근로자명", "생년월일"])
        국민기본 = 국민기본.iloc[: , -1 : ].copy()
        국민기본["개인부담금"] = 국민기본.결정보험료/2 
        국민기본["사업주부담금"] = 국민기본.결정보험료/2 
        국민기본.drop(columns = ["결정보험료"], inplace=True)
    return render(request, "index.html")

def employ_upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        file3 = request.FILES.get("employ_input")
        고용기본 = pd.read_excel(file3,header = 1) 
        생년월일통일 = 고용기본["생년월일"].replace("-", "", inplace = True, regex = True)
        고용기본 = 고용기본.set_index(["근로자명", "생년월일"]) 
        고용기본2 = 고용기본.iloc[: , -3 : ].copy()
        고용기본2.columns = ["개인부담금_고용", "사업주실업급여보험료", "사업주고안직능보험료"] 
        고용기본2["사업주부담금"] = 고용기본2.사업주실업급여보험료 + 고용기본2.사업주고안직능보험료 
        고용기본2.drop(columns = ["사업주실업급여보험료", "사업주고안직능보험료"], inplace=True) 
    return render(request, "index.html")

def industrial_upload(request): 
    if request.method == "POST":
        file4 = request.FILES.get("industrial_input")
        산업 = pd.read_excel(file4)
        주민번호통일 = 산업["생년월일"].replace("-", "", inplace = True, regex = True) 
        산업기본 = 산업.set_index(["근로자명", "생년월일"])
        산업기본2 = 산업기본.iloc[: , -1 : ].copy() 
        산업기본2.columns = ["사업주부담금"] 
    return render(request, "index.html")

def institute_combine(request): 
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "index.html")
    elif request.method == "POST":
        건강기본 = request.FILES.get("건강기본")
        국민기본 = request.FILES.get("국민기본")
        고용기본2 = request.FILES.get("고용기본2")
        산업기본2 = request.FILES.get("산업기본2")
        print(산업기본2)
        건강국민 = 건강기본.merge(국민기본, how = "outer", on = ["근로자명", "생년월일"], suffixes= ("_건강", "_국민"), indicator= True ) 
        건강국민.drop(columns = ["_merge"], inplace=True) 
        건강국민 = 건강국민.fillna(0) 

        고용산재2= 고용기본2.merge(산업기본2, how = "outer", on = ["근로자명", "생년월일"], suffixes= ("_고용", "_산재"), indicator= True ) # 고용보험, 산재보험 합치기
        고용산재2.drop(columns = ["_merge"], inplace=True)
        고용산재2 = 고용산재2.fillna(0)

        건강국민고용산재 = 건강국민.merge(고용산재2, how = "outer", on = ["근로자명", "생년월일"], suffixes= ("_건강", "_국민"), indicator= True ) 
        건강국민고용산재.drop(columns = ["_merge"], inplace=True) 
        건강국민고용산재 = 건강국민고용산재.fillna(0) # Nan값 0으로 교체
        건강국민고용산재["사업주부담금합"] = 건강국민고용산재.사업주부담금_건강 + 건강국민고용산재.사업주부담금_국민 + 건강국민고용산재.사업주부담금_고용 + 건강국민고용산재.사업주부담금_산재
        건강국민고용산재 = 건강국민고용산재.sort_index() 
        건강국민고용산재.reset_index(inplace = True) 
        건강국민고용산재["직종"] = ""
        건강국민고용산재 = 건강국민고용산재.reindex(columns = ['직종', '근로자명', '생년월일', '개인부담금_건강', '사업주부담금_건강', '개인부담금_국민', '사업주부담금_국민',
        '개인부담금_고용', '사업주부담금_고용', '사업주부담금_산재', '사업주부담금합']) 
        with BytesIO() as b:
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(b, engine="openpyxl")
            건강국민고용산재.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sample_sheet")
            writer.close()
            response_data = b.getvalue()

        return HttpResponse(
            response_data,
            content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        )
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

index.html

```
<h1>건강보험</h1>

    <form action="health_upload/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id = "health_input" type="file" name="health_input" class="form-control" accept=".xlsx">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>

<h1>국민연금</h1>

    <form action="national_upload/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id = "national_input" type="file" name="national_input" class="form-control" accept=".xlsx">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>

<h1>고용보험</h1>

    <form action="employ_upload/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id = "employ_input" type="file" name="employ_input" class="form-control" accept=".xlsx">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>

<h1>산재보험</h1>

    <form action="industrial_upload/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id = "industrial_input" type="file" name="industrial_input" class="form-control" accept=".xlsx">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>

<h1>합친파일받기</h1>
```

```
<form action="institute_combine/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %} 
<button type="submit">download</button>
</form>
```

try

## 합친파일받기

click download button

occured error at django
TypeError at /institute_combine/
'method' object is not subscriptable

or def institute_combine(request):
건강기본 = request.FILES.get("건강기본") code changed to 건강기본 = request.FILES["건강기본"]

MultiValueDictKeyError at /institute_combine/
'건강기본'